# Kendo Grid Updating with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-grid

Problem is probably in success function 
RssCek Function in HomeController returns succesfully. But i cant manage bind with grid
**HomeController RssCek function return part**

```
        return Json(feedler, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**JavaScript Script Function**

```
<script>
    function select(e) {
        var value = $(e.item).find("> .k-link").text();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("RssCek", "Home")',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: { value: value },
                success: function (feedler)
                {
                    var g = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

                    g.dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: feedler });
                    g.dataSource.read();
                    g.refresh();
                },
                error: function (request, status, error)
                {document.write(request+"++"+ status+"++"+ error);}
                });
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the datasource of the kendo grid like this ,

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data:feedler 

});
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

The best method you can do is to define the transport properties of the data source of the grid. You don't have to create datasouces for each data read, you [can specify read,create,update methods](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport) in the datasouce itself and then you can call ,

```
var g = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
 g.dataSource.read();
```

Whenever you need to refresh from server.

Comment: Thanks for help, but it didn't work. feedler is Json type maybe problem can be there?

Comment: That should be the data array?

Comment: did you check the response from server with firebug?Any error you get ?

Comment: function return 6 Rss element but problem at binding kendo.grid() my workmate said 'Kendo Ui grid has bugs with ajax refreshing, use partial view' and i decided to use partial view thanks for helping

Comment: np .I don't think it has bugs like this , I have used ajax refreshing several times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<script>
    function select(e) {
        var value = $(e.item).find("> .k-link").text();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("RssCek", "Home")',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: { value: value },
                success: function (feedler)
                {





 $("#grid1").html('');
                       $("#grid1").kendoGrid({
                       dataSource: feedler,
                       sortable: true,
                       pageable: {
                           refresh: true,
                              pageSizes: true
                              },
                            columns: [{
                                         field: "SampleDescription",
                                       width: 90,
                                     }, {
                            field: "SampleCode",
                              width: 90,
                               }, {
                                 width: 100,
                                field: "SampleItems"
                                  }
                                 ]
                                });;
                },
                error: function (request, status, error)
                {document.write(request+"++"+ status+"++"+ error);}
                });
    }

</script>
```

**View**

```
<div id="grid1">
    </div>
```

OR with same grid

```
  <script>
        function select(e) {
            var value = $(e.item).find("> .k-link").text();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("RssCek", "Home")',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: { value: value },
                success: function (feedler)
                {


                $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: result });
                    $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                    $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").refresh();
}

</script>
```

Field Name is just for example.

Comment: This created a new grid every time you call  `select(e)` function

Comment: i tried but it didn't worked 

 `var feedler = from feed in rssXml.Descendants("item")
                          select new Rss
                          {
                              
                              Baslik = feed.Element("title").Value,
                              Link = "<a href=\"" + feed.Element("link").Value + "\">Oku</a>",
                              Aciklama=feed.Element("description").Value
                          };`

i wrote fields in your code Aciklama,Baslik and Link. it is true, isn't it?